# Map using API key is not appearing

Tags: html, css

I am following the tutorial to load google map using API. Why map is not showing up? I created API key by following tutorial.

```js
function initMap(){
    var options = {
        zoom:8,
        center:{lat:37.7749,lng:-122.4194}
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('#map'),options);
}
```

```css
#map{
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCRkjqdbub6Tmlus_CPROfEXnAtrQxWubM&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" async></script> 
<h1>My google Map</h1>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the `map` id as a query selector. Instead of `document.getElementById('#map')`, you need to have `document.getElementById('map')`.

Or if you prefer to use the query selector syntax, then you can use `document.querySelector('#map')`

Comment: I tried that earlier and now also. It's not working.

Comment: Are there any console errors? Are you sure your css is loading properly?

Comment: I tried this codepen and it is working there. But not in my program which has some other html , css code.  Link for CodePen is     https://codepen.io/ash0101/pen/GRNPPNa

Comment: Yes there was a css error. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @Ash, please accept the answer if it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Css is not the problem here, you must do it again with another tut